# Python doctest says failed but returns correct value

Tags: python, doctest

I was preforming some doctests in PyCharm and I ran the test in the python console. It passes one and fails the other, but the failure shows the value returned being the correct value. Does anyone know what I might be missing or if this is a known error in PyCharm, etc?

Here is the code

```
def friend_date(a, b):
    """
    Returns True if they have any hobbies in common, False is not.

    >>> elmo = ('Elmo', 5, ['hugging', 'being nice'])
    >>> sauron = ('Sauron', 5000, ['killing hobbits', 'chess'])
    >>> gandalf = ('Gandalf', 10000, ['waving wands', 'chess'])

    >>> friend_date(elmo, sauron)
    False

    >>> friend_date(sauron, gandalf)
    True 
    """
    return bool(set(a[2]) & set(b[2]))
```

Comment: Your `True` line has a trailing space. That matters.

Comment: Didn't realize spaces mattered like that in python, only thought it mattered to indent properly. Thank you so much @user2357112supportsMonica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed as @user2357112 pointed out you have space in the expected output for your second test case. I tested with this code and it worked:

```
def friend_date(a, b):
    """
    Returns True if they have any hobbies in common, False is not.

    >>> elmo = ('Elmo', 5, ['hugging', 'being nice'])
    >>> sauron = ('Sauron', 5000, ['killing hobbits', 'chess'])
    >>> gandalf = ('Gandalf', 10000, ['waving wands', 'chess'])

    >>> friend_date(elmo, sauron)
    False

    >>> friend_date(sauron, gandalf)
    True
    """
    return bool(set(a[2]) & set(b[2]))
```

Comment: @brent-franklin if it answers your question please mark it as resolved.